# What should I use to have users log into my ASP.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Should I create a userControl with two labels, two textboxes(for user/pass) and a button for submit?

Am I approaching this in the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it's safer and faster to use ASP.NET Membership provider and embeded Login controls

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx